# Can't login to outlook with selenium

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to solve practice project from automation the boring stuff with python3 book
where i'm asked to build program with selenium . where it find the email input and password and assign it to the fields how ever when i do all of that i've found myself struggling with clicking on submit button it give me selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException error
Here is what i  done :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1617646022&rver=7.0.6737.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1%26RpsCsrfState%3da6d2e9e1-99f2-5a9e-6194-166e3842c959&id=292841&aadredir=1&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=90015'

#login 

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)

emailInput = driver.find_element_by_id('i0116')
emailInput.send_keys('email@hotmail.com')

submit = driver.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9')
passwordInput = driver.find_element_by_id('i0118')
passwordInput.send_keys('passwordsomthing')
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this code and it works.  Please let me know if you have any issues.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument("--test-type")
firefox_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=firefox_options)

driver.get('https://login.live.com/')

username_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.input.text-box')))
username_box.send_keys('test@outlook.com')

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

next_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button.primary')
next_button.click()

password_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.input.text-box')))
password_box.send_keys('somepassword')

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button.primary')
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: it works but this beyond my understanding atm

Comment: @seprico I'm glad that it worked for you.  Please accept the answer for solving your issue.